# Azure DiagnosticMonitor API is now obsolete

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-diagnostics

We are currently in the process of doing some overhauls to our WorkerRole on Azure.  Our current implementation uses the DiagnosticsMonitor to automatically put all of the trace and error information into the WAD-Logs table in our storage account and works well.  However, as we are implementing the Diagnostics portion of the role in our rewrite, ReSharper is diligently informing me that `DiagnosticMonitor` is now an obsolete API.  However, I cannot find any information that shows what is meant to replace this API.

Some relevant information (all of these should be latest versions via NuGet):

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics :: version 2.5.0.0
>
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration:: version 3.0.0.0
>
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime:: version 2.5.0.0
>
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage:: version 4.3.0.0

The code we are attempting to replicate

```
    public static void ConfigureDiagnostics()
            {
//warning here on DiagnosticMonitor
                var config = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();
                config.ConfigurationChangePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1d);
                config.Logs.BufferQuotaInMB = 500;
                config.Logs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.LogLevel.Error;
                config.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1d);
//warning here on DiagnosticMonitor 
                DiagnosticMonitor.StartWithConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("LogStorageConnectionString"), config);
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was the "old" way of doing the diagnostics and we're deprecating this solution in favor of the new XML based one, meaning you can also remotely configure the Diagnostics infrastructure etc.

More info you can find [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2014/12/02/windows-azure-diagnostics-upgrading-from-azure-sdk-2-4-to-azure-sdk-2-5.aspx) on how to migrate as well.

Comment: You can also get a list of the breaking changes here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn873976.aspx#BKMK_breaking

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis, my Google-fu must be weak on a saturday afternoon.  This looks promising (and easier than before).

Comment: No worries, that's why we're here for my friend :)